# How do you cleanly uninstall the Eclipse MapReduce plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to get the eclipse plugin for hadoop development to work, I'm using hadoop 0.18.3. I installed the old MapReduce plugin (http://www.alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/mapreducetools) on Eclipse v3.5.2 (M20100211-1343) by copying it to /Applications/eclipse/plugins and restarting eclipse but that didn't work, I figured it was because it was developed for older versions of hadoop and eclipse (circa 2007). Then I realized that the hadoop distribution has a jar under contrib/eclipse-plugin - so copied that to /Application/eclipse/plugins and restarted... then things got funky. So I tried to remove them both so I could start over but that fails, when I go to 'Window -> Open Perspective -> Other' there's a "ghost" of the old plugin ... no icon, it just says '' (literally surrounded by angle brackets).

I can't seem to revert eclipse to a clean prior state - I'm tempted to just start over with a fresh eclipse install but that'd be a lot of work (installing other plugins like git and pydev plus re-creating the workspace). So how do you cleanly uninstall the Eclipse MapReduce plugin?

Alternatively: how do I get the eclipse hadoop plugin properly installed, connected to the local tasktracker and development HDFS for hadoop 0.18.3?

Answer (score 2):

there is no way on uninstalling , you just delete the hadoop-eclipse-plugin.jar from the plugins folder in eclipse and refresh eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about hadoop and mapreduce, but you should look at the `features` folder as well as `plugins`. Anyway, that should be the only places that well-behaved plugins install themselves. But did you say that you dropped a file into `plugins`? Then there shouldn't be anything else to do.

I've never heard of `contrib/eclipse-plugin`, where is that? Not in the eclipse folder I think; I've never seen it.

It is possible that you should start eclipse with `-clean`, but that's not supposed to be needed any more with 3.5. Alternately you could try with a new workspace, which you don't like, but it would start with new metadata and that would tell you it was the metadata and not code in the `plugins` directory.